# Adobe flex dateField

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, datefield

I have some code as follows:

```
private function onComboChange(evt:Event):void {
  var temp:Date = df_date.selectedDate;
  temp.date += 5;
  df_dateDue.selectedDate = new Date(temp);
}
```

In essence, I am trying to add 5 days onto the selected date in df_date, and put that date into df_dateDue. This fires off via an EventListener on a combobox. Both df_date and df_dateDue are dateFields.

OK, so the first time that I run this, it works fine; df_date stays the same and df_dateDue is set to 5 days past df_date. However, the next time that I run it, df_dateDue increments by 10 days from df_date, the next time by 15, and so on.

So, stepping through the code shows that somehow df_date has become linked to the temp var, and that the temp var is not resetting itself each time the function is called.

Example: df_date = 01 Jan, df_dateDue = 01 Jan.

1. Fire off the event, df_date = 01 Jan, df_dateDue = 06 Jan
2. Fire off the event again. At this point, var temp = 06 Jan (even though df_date still shows 01 Jan), and df_dateDue is then set to 11 Jan
3. Fire off the event again. At this point var temp = 11 Jan (even though df_date = 01 Jan), and df_dateDue is then set to 16 Jan

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flex/AS, variables that contain objects are really just pointers to some memory space.  Date's in Flex are an Object, not a native type.  This line:

```
var temp:Date = df_date.selectedDate;
```

Creates a new pointer to an existing date object.  It does not create a copy.

This line:

```
temp.date += 5;
```

increments the date property of the dateObject.  All references pointing to that date object will be updated.  Try using [objectUtil.copy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#copy())

```
var temp:Date = ObjectUtil.copy(df_date.selectedDate) as Date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to make the following change though, since it seems that ObjectUtil cant copy a Date object.var temp:Object = ObjectUtil.copy(view.df_date); var d:Date = temp.selectedDate;

Comment: @jonoB You probably could have cast it in one line.  I'll update my answer.